# Creating a Series of four Numbers

Tags: java, numbers, rounding

In an Interview, they asked me to write a java program. the question is like this ,

There is a start and end number.divide the number between start and end by 4 equal parts, and print its 10s power.
Example if start =110, end=1234

the result is to get

```
300
600
900 
1000
```

i have done a code to divide the it into 4 parts but i am not able to round up to 10s power.
My code is

```
double start = 110;
double end = 1234;
double n = 4;
double difference = (end - start) / n;
double value = start;
while (value < end)
{
  value += difference;
  System.out.println(value);
}
ouput/
```

391.0
672.0
953.0
1234.0
how to round my values ?

Comment: Hold on.. **300 600 900 1000** : There is a typo right 1000 --> 1200..?

Comment: You could actually just do `((Double)value).intValue())/100 *100` and you'd get the results rounded down.

Answer (score 1):

For each `value`, use base 10 logarithm to get its 10th power. For instance:

```
int log_10 = (int) Math.log10(value); // For 391.0, result is 2
```

Then, its easy:

```
long basePower = (long) Math.pow(10, log_10); // Yoy get 100
int result = ((int) (value/basePower)) * basePower; // You get 300
```

Same for the other values:

```
1234.0 ==>
    log_10 = 3; 
    basePower = 1000; 
    (int) (1234.0/1000) = 1 ==> result = 1*1000 = 1000;
```

Comment: is it possible to do the same logic in javascript or jquery

Comment: I think so using [javascript `Math`library](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/math.shtml), but as far as I know, javascript doesn't have a `log_10` function. However, `log_10(x) = log(x)/log(10)`, where `log_10` is base `10` logarithm, and `log` is base `E` logarithm. Javascript does have a `log()` function